# InspectIT APM - Cannot see dig deep down in methods

Tags: java

I have configured InspectIT and a sample springboot application . there is a request mapping which was configured to leak some memory .. trouble is InspectIT does not dig deep into the method calls .

the only level it goes down is doFilter-> service and then no method calls after that .. is this normal for inspectit ? ... somehow i would have expected it to dig deep down into the method calls

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add instrumentation rules for your application to "dig deeper". The `doFilter` and `service` methods are instrumented by default as part of the HTTP instrumentation profile. In addition to the HTTP profile, by default inspectIT instruments SQL statement executions, other entry points into your application (like JMS), the places where external HTTP/JMS calls are done and Java Executors. There are some other common instrumentation profiles (Hibernate, SQL parameters, Spring, etc), but you need to enable them by yourself.

Usually, you would start with the default settings and then, in addition, add instrumentation rules related to your application.